# rel="canonical" html5 unable to validate

Tags: validation, html

Should the link attribute `rel="canonical"` validate against html5?

It is the first time I am using this and I am getting the following validation errors:

"Bad value canonical for attribute rel on element link: Keyword canonical is not registered."

It kind of suggests it shouldnt although I cant find any concrete documentation on this.

Edit - Here is the line that is throwing the validator off:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://dev.local/" />
```

I have  tried it with and  without the closing slash

Comment: Show us the actual code which isn't validating

Answer (score 4):

Validator is marking canonical invalid because canonical is a recent addition (as Gutmann pointed out) and the validation tool does not update real time.  The W3C tells us why canonical is on the Micorformats wiki but does not validate. It is because the updates of wiki data in the validator are manual.

You will see this in the validation reporting:
"A whitespace-separated list of link types listed as allowed on  in the HTML specification or listed as an allowed on  on the Microformats wiki without duplicate keywords in the list. **Note that updates of the wiki data in the validator are manual and do not happen in real time**"

This will validate on their next manual update.

Answer (score 2):

There is no definition for the `canonical` `rel` [in the HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#linkTypes), but it does also say that:

> The `rel` attribute has no default value. If the attribute is omitted or if none of the values in the attribute are recognized by the user agent, then the document has no particular relationship with the destination resource other than there being a hyperlink between the two.

So, it's not technically conforming HTML5, but it will simply be ignored by UAs which don't understand it.

Comment: So your saying then that the validator is correct in marking the page as invalid?

Comment: Well, the HTML5 spec does allow anyone to register a new `rel` at http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values. The W3C conformance checker (*not* strictly a "validator") does say that it may be "unreliable, or not perfectly up to date with the latest development of some cutting-edge technologies". So no, it's not necessarily correct to say your page is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Use this `data-rel`

```
<link data-rel="canonical" href="http://dev.local/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from the output of the validator and the part of the spec that defines the link's [rel](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-rel) attribute I'd say the validator is marking the document as invalid due to the "canonical" type being only a proposal and not part of the [official linkTypes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes) right now.

At the same time that page also says ...

> Types defined as extensions in the
>   Microformats wiki existing-rel-values
>   page with the status "proposed" or
>   "ratified" may be used with the rel
>   attribute on link, a, and area
>   elements in accordance to the "Effect
>   on..." field. [MFREL]

The validation message refers to [this list](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) of currently valid extensions to the "official catalog". 
Up until June 2 this list did not contain the canonical link type so the validator was IMO correct in marking the document as invalid.

But now that the canonical type *is* is in the list of proposed types, I think this is just a matter of time before also the validator will recognize it :-)

Comment: Why would validator be correct in marking it invalid if "canonical" is listed on that link?

Comment: LOL, misread the whole section. Sorry for that. Will my reply ASAP.

Comment: And if you look at when canonical was added to that list you will notice, that it happened last night ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In error description they do reference [Microformats wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) as list of valid link types, their list contains "canonical" link type.

I believe that this a temporary bug in validator because it reported error for rel="canonical" only on my HTML5 website, but not on my other XHTML website.